# How can i add or delete multiple divs in the same page

Tags: jquery

I need to add two text boxes to a `div`.

If I click my add button, one more `div` needs to display with the two text boxes.

I also need help with the delete function.

Please help.

Comment: Please try spend a little bit more time formatting your question before you post it. You should also post the code you've got/ tried and give your own feedback on where you're having problems. We're here to help, not to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function for your add button. then you can use the [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function to remove the the chosen div..

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has some nice documentation about HTML Manipulation: [jQuery API: Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Be sure to check out functions like `.append()`:

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Example:

```
$('div.container').append('<div>New box!</div>');
```

Result:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Old box
  </div>
  <div>
    New box!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a quick implementation I did with jQuery and using an array to store elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/cN5SR/130/

You can easly understand the code if you know a bit of jQuery and basic javascript.

Cheers